# "Do not backup" method for iOS 5.1 not working?

Tags: ios, ios5, icloud

We are stuck in a review process.

The Apple reviewers says that we are not setting the "do not backup" flag for the files that we need in our application.

Certainly the first time we did forget about marking the files with that flag. But second time we used the methods described here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

But it didn't get working, and the app was rejected again.

Debugging and trying once and again, the files never get marked as "do not backup" using the method that Apple says that we need to use in iOS 5.1

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL

{

    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);



    NSError *error = nil;

    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]

                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];

    if(!success){

        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);

    }

    return success;

}
```

But if we use the method that they say that we need to use in iOS 5.0.1 the files are being well marked and not being backed up in iCloud.

```
#import <sys/xattr.h>

- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL

{

    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);



    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];



    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";

    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;



    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);

    return result == 0;

}
```

But the trouble is that is that doc page Apple says that this method is deprecated. So I am affraid that we use the method that works (the one for iOS 5.0.1) upload again the app and could reject again the application for the same issue.

So the docs says one thing, but this thing is not working as properly.

Did somebody get this issue working? And the Apple reviewers doesn't say nothing us about this trouble and how to solve so that we could be 100% alined with what the spects.